# Java - How to accept only integers on date input?

Tags: java, date, integer, java.util.scanner

Hey guys so my project for checking a user's input of a date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy works, but now I need to modify it so that it rejects anything not numbers. For example if I input 12/5/abcd or aa/12/2014 it should return me an error. At the moment if I enter a char or letters into the program it'll give an error saying something like "you should enter only valid integers". I'm using a delimiter for "/" to separate months and days and \r or enter/return at the end of the year to finish the user input.

Comment: Ok.  Did you try anything?

Comment: What have you done so far? Regex?

Answer (score 1):

Only integer check won't work (consider someone enters `30-02-2013`

you need to validate Date specifically, You should use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with [`setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put an if condition to check the instance of integer on dd, mm and yy. Like

```
if(x instanceof Integer){
         ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, use Java regular expression to validate the input date using below regex.

`([0-9]{2})\\([0-9]{2})\\([0-9]{4})`

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about digits vs non-digits, you can validate with a simple regular expression.

```
import java.util.regex.*;


public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original =  "12/24/1014";
        Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}");
        System.out.println(mypattern.matcher(original).matches());
        // If not true, throw error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  below date.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

    boolean isValidDate(string input) {
         try {
              format.parse(input);
              return true;
         }
         catch(ParseException e){
              return false;
         }
    }
```